# Inheritance initialize parameters

Tags: ruby, inheritance, initialization, subclass, super

I was wondering how to properly initialize the subclass "Computer." I want it to inherit the attributes in initialize in the Game class, except for #start, which is a method. I am also unsure of how to handle parameters in the initialize method in this case. Does anyone know an elegant way to rephrase it? Thanks.

```
class Game
    attr_reader :input, :clues

    def initialize
        colors = %w(R O Y G I V)
        code = []
        all = ''
        count = 0
        start
    end

    def start
        ...
    end

    def ask_input
        ...
    end

class Computer < Game
    attr_reader :input, :clues
    def initialize
        colors = %w(R O Y G I V)
        code = []
        all = ''
        count = 0
        ask_input
        computer_turn
    end
 .....
 end
```

Comment: One way - don't even do it in `initialize`, but define a custom setter, e.g. `def colors; @colors ||= %w(R O Y G I V); end` on `Game`, which will then be available in `Computer`.

Comment: Though I'd generally recommend restructuring your variables into custom setter methods for cleaner inheritance, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728735/inherit-class-level-instance-variables-in-ruby) for answers to the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to inherit the attributes in initialize in the Game class, except for #start, which is a method.

All attributes and methods will be inherited. You did this correctly with:

```
class Computer < Game
```

You don't need the `attr_reader` because it is inherited from Game.

> I am also unsure of how to handle parameters in the initialize method in this case.

You can do something like the following. It takes an input as the parameter. Consider:

```
computer = Computer.new( :foo )
```

After the computer is initialized, it's `input` is equal to `:foo`.

```
class Computer < Game
  def initialize input
    @input = input
    ...
```

See:

```
computer.input
=> :foo
```

Comment: I don't want Computer to inherit #start. I want it to start with ask_input instead. It doesn't work as it is written above.

Comment: You can mark `start` as private, so it will not be inherited.

Answer (score 1):

> I am also unsure of how to handle parameters in the initialize method in this case

You just

- Add `super` in the `initializer` of a sub-class to call the `initializer` of its super-class.
- And for sure, all instance variables should have `@` char at beginning to make they usable though all instance menthods.
- Also remove `attr_reader` from the `Computer` class, because it will be inherited from `Game` class

> I want it to inherit the attributes in initialize in the Game class, except for #start, which is a method

- Finally, to avoid call the method `#start` of `Game` class, I think that you just need to override it in `Computer` class

Result code

```
    class Game
      attr_reader :input, :clues

      def initialize
        @colors = %w(R O Y G I V)
        @code = []
        @all = ''
        @count = 0
        start
      end

      def ask_input
        # sample value for @input 
        @input = 'sample input'
      end

      def start
        puts "start"
      end
    end

    class Computer < Game
      #attr_reader :input, :clues

      def initialize
        super
        ask_input
        computer_turn
      end

      def start
        # Do nothing
      end

      def computer_turn
        puts "computer_turn"
        p @colors
      end
    end


    comp = Computer.new
    # The string "start" is not puts here because Game#start is not called
    => computer_turn
    => ["R", "O", "Y", "G", "I", "V"]

    comp.input
    => "sample input"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the method `start`, just eliminate it from your `Game` class so that it wouldn't appear on your subclasses. Something like :

```
class Game
    attr_reader :input, :clues

    def initialize
        colors = %w(R O Y G I V)
        code = []
        all = ''
        count = 0
        (Insert what start does here)
    end


    def ask_input
        ... 
    end
```

Then, just override the initialize of your `Computer` subclass with:

```
def initialize
    colors = %w(R O Y G I V)
    code = []
    all = ''
    count = 0
    (insert other functionalities)
end
```

You can also eliminate the redundant `attr_reader` since it has been inherited from `Game`