# Class instance variable not available to child class?

Tags: ruby, class-variables, class-instance-variables

I want to leverage class methods on child classes in ruby, but those that rely on child instance variables are not working. I was told "don't use class variables! (@@)", so I'm not. How can I make class `B` do what I want, namely print out `"1"`?

```
class A
  @a = "1"

  def initialize
    self.class.what_is_a
  end

  def self.what_is_a
    p @a
  end
end

class B < A
end


A.what_is_a
B.what_is_a
A.new
B.new
```

The output:

```
"1"
nil
"1"
nil
```

I'd like them all to be `"1"`.

Comment: hello, have you considered using protected methods instead of instance variables?

Comment: Can you show me how that would work?

Comment: Well, depending on the exact usecase, class variables might be the appropriate solution here. `B` is a different instance than `A`, so no wonder you don't get "1". It is not clear what you _actually_ want to do, so I can't offer any alternatives.

Comment: I thought I explained what I want to do. I want B to print out "1". That is to say, I want B to have access to As class state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inherit class-level instance variables in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728735/inherit-class-level-instance-variables-in-ruby)

Comment: "I want B to have access to As class state" - easy, you can refer to instance of A from within B by using `superclass`. For example: https://pastebin.com/uD9UHRbK.

Comment: That makes sense - I just thought it was kind of hacky...I figured I would get this pass through inheritance for free. There is no easy way to do what I want without having to write that kind of code in all child classes?

Comment: @skaz: yep, inheritance does not apply here. You want to access another object's state, you need to explicitly address the object.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ahh, ok. So when I inherit A from B and make an instance, A and B is one object with shared state, and their classes are each objects as well with their own states, is that right?

Comment: *"those that rely on child instance variables are not working"* -- `@a = "1"` inside class `A` doesn't create an instance property. Move the assignment inside `initialize` to get an instance property.

Comment: @skaz: not really, A and B __are__ classes/objects, each with their own state.

Comment: @axiac: nope, that'd make instance variable. He wants class instance variable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But then wouldn't the same logic apply if A and B are two objects? You said "You want to access another object's state"...
Wouldn't this also be accessing another object's state, if B is a different object:

`class B

  attr_reader :a

  def initialize
    @a = 1
  end
end

class A < B
end
`

puts A.new.a
puts B.new.a


And yet inheritance works here. It isn't clear to me why it doesn't work on the class level. I would expect the same thing to happen.

EDIT: not sure how to format better...

Comment: @skaz: "And yet inheritance works here" - nope, state is not inherited in this example (or ever). _Behaviour_ is. When initializer is executed, it defines instance variable `@a` on __whatever__ is the current object (instance of `A` or `B`, in this case).

Comment: @skaz: it may not make any sense right now. But don't worry, it will "click" one day :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "class instance variable". Classes are objects like any other object, they can have instance variables just like any other object. Instance variables belong to instances (objects). `A` and `B` are different objects, they cannot access each other's instance variables.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: it's an instance variable on a class object. Making it... "class instance variable"? :) Pedantry aside (you're right there, of course), we need a short name for this type of variables, to tell them apart from the "regular" instance variables, even if the name is not entirely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Using protected methods

```
class A   
  def initialize
    self.class.what_is_a
  end

  def self.what_is_a
    puts a
  end

  protected 

  def self.a
    '1'
  end
end

class B < A
end


A.what_is_a # >> 1
B.what_is_a # >> 1
A.new # >> 1
B.new # >> 1
```

Comment: That does not use instance variable (state).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev agreed, not sure if he needs it